# IntegrateWithEnvers error

Tags: nhibernate-envers

I am trying to start using nhibernate envers and I seem to be getting an error whenever trying to configure it.  I'm only trying to setup auditing on a single entity for now to try to keep it somewhat simple.  I am getting the following error:

```
An audited relation from Entities.Product.ProductUoms to a not audited entity Entities.ProductUom!
```

I setup my auditing like this:

```
var enversConf = new FluentConfiguration();

enversConf.Audit<Product>();
          .ExcludeRelationData("productUoms")
          .ExcludeRelationData(x => x.ProductUoms);

// instanceConfiguration.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix", string.Empty); // default
nhibernateConfiguration.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_audit"); // default _AUD
nhibernateConfiguration.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.revision_field_name", "revision"); // default
nhibernateConfiguration.Properties.Add("nhibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name", "revision_type"); // default

nhibernateConfiguration.IntegrateWithEnvers(metaDataProvider: enversConf);
```

In my product entity I have the following properties:

```
private IList<ProductUom> productUoms;
public virtual IEnumerable<ProductUom> ProductUoms { get { return this.productUoms.Select(x => x); } }
```

They are mapped in Fluent NHibernate like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.ProductUoms)
            .KeyColumn("PROD_ID")
            .Inverse()
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select();
```

It seems like the error being thrown should be avoided because I'm explicitly trying to exclude the auditing of that relationship.  Not quite sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: It appears this is a 4 year old bug. https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE-111  Seems like such a common use case I'm surprised this hasn't been fixed by now.